# how to make slide show from List of images in android

Tags: android, timer, slideshow, universal-image-loader, picasso

I have made an android app,In that I am getting an arrayList of ImageUrls,I want to make an automated lsideShow in android by using this arrayLis,I have tried as below using thread but It gives me arrayIndexOPutOfBounds exception,It goes to second image abd then gives exception,Please help me to save me,My code is as below:

```
resultArray = new ArrayList<String>();
iv_paly.setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListener()){

@Override
OnClick(){
            imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(1), proImage, options);
            proImage.postDelayed(swapImage, 3000);
}
MediaPlayer introSound, bellSound;
    Runnable swapImage = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= resultArray.size(); i++) {
                imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(i), proImage, options);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
       package com.example.imagegal;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.content.Context;
       import android.view.Menu;
       import android.view.MenuItem;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.view.ViewGroup;
       import android.view.Window;
       import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
       import android.widget.AdapterView;
       import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
       import android.widget.Gallery;
        import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
       import android.widget.ImageView;
       import android.widget.ViewSwitcher; 
       import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
       import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
        android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
        android.R.anim.slide_in_left));

Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}

public View makeView() {
ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
return i;
}

private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

   i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
    return i;
}

private Context mContext;

}

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
    R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,
    R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d};

private Integer[] mImageIds = {
    R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c,
    R.drawable.d};

}
```

xml file

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

<ImageSwitcher android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
/>

<Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:background="#55000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:spacing="16dp"
/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sir,I have tried it,It is working upto second image then I got IndexOutOfBOunds exception..pls help

Comment: private Integer[] mThumbIds & Integer[] mImageIds must be in same size, if you run on and emulator ,don't put images which contain large data size, because then you will get out of memory exeception